# I am not sure, why does my java buffered reader code only read last line of CSV file?

Tags: java, csv

I've created a method that will read the contents of a CSV file and pass it through my object(bankaccount). I am not sure, why does it only read the last line of my csv file. Can any one figure it out/ or help me to read csv and convert it to java object?

My code:

```
public static ArrayList<bankAccount> readCSV(File f){
        ArrayList<bankAccount> accounts = new ArrayList<>();

        try{
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
            String line = br.readLine();
            while (line != null){
                String[] atrib = line.split(",");

                int id = Integer.parseInt(atrib[0]);
                String n = atrib[1];
                double b = Double.parseDouble(atrib[2]);

                bankAccount newacc = new bankAccount(id,n,b);
                accounts.add(newacc);
                line = br.readLine();
            }

            br.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return accounts;
    }
```

CSV FIle:

```
123,Ac,1000
456,Aundrea,2000
789,Nicole,300
321,Draku,2990
```

Expected Output:

```
Acc Num: 321
Acc Name: Draku
Acc Bal: 2990.0

Acc Num: 321
Acc Name: Draku
Acc Bal: 2990.0

Acc Num: 321
Acc Name: Draku
Acc Bal: 2990.0

Acc Num: 321
Acc Name: Draku
Acc Bal: 2990.0
```

Comment: Does your `bankAccount` class (which should be named `BankAccount`) contain static variables?

Comment: Yes it does:private static int accountNumber;
    private static String accountName;
    private static double balance;

Comment: Why are they static? They should be member variables instead

Comment: Codewise your csv parsing block looks okay to me.  Could you please share definition of `bankAccount` class? I think there might be some problems there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your BankAccount attributes to non static because they belong to the instance

```
public class Test {
    
        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            
            
            ArrayList<BankAccount> list = readCSV(new File("your path"));
            
            
            System.out.println(list);
            
            
            
        }
        
        public static ArrayList<BankAccount> readCSV(File f){
             ArrayList<BankAccount> accounts = new ArrayList<>();
    
            try{
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
                String line = br.readLine();
                while (line != null){
                    String[] atrib = line.split(",");
    
                    int id = Integer.parseInt(atrib[0]);
                    String n = atrib[1];
                    double b = Double.parseDouble(atrib[2]);
    
                    BankAccount newacc = new BankAccount(id,n,b);
                    accounts.add(newacc);
                    line = br.readLine();
                }
    
                br.close();
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    
            return accounts;
        }
            
        }
        
    
    class BankAccount{
        
        
        private int id;
        private String n;
        private double b;
    
        public BankAccount(int id, String n, double b) {
            this.id = id;
            this.n = n;
            this.b = b;
        }
    
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
    
        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    
        public String getN() {
            return n;
        }
    
        public void setN(String n) {
            this.n = n;
        }
    
        public double getB() {
            return b;
        }
    
        public void setB(double b) {
            this.b = b;
        }
        
        public String toString(){
            
            
            return id + " : " + n + " : " + b;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Already there are some answers. I tried to code this, just share that here:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class BankReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BankReader bankReader = new BankReader();
        bankReader.readCSV(new File("data.csv"));

    }
    
    
    public List<BankAccount> readCSV(File f){
        List<BankAccount> accounts = new ArrayList<>();

        try{
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
            String line = br.readLine();
            while (line != null){
                String[] atrib = line.split(",");

                int id = Integer.parseInt(atrib[0]);
                String n = atrib[1];
                double b = Double.parseDouble(atrib[2]);

                BankAccount newAcc = new BankAccount(id,n,b);
                System.out.println(newAcc);
                accounts.add(newAcc);
                
                
                line = br.readLine();
            }

            br.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return accounts;
    }

}

class BankAccount{
    

    int id;
    String name;
    double balance;
    
    public BankAccount(int id, String name, double balance) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.balance = balance;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "BankAccount [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", balance=" + balance + "]";
    }
}
```